# How to resolve JS compiler errors when running npm run watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I'm running into an issue with npm run watch erroring out when I try to run the command so my ReactJS code can compile. `npm install --save` works without an issue, but when I get to `npm run watch` It fails and throws back the following: [image]

I've tried fully deleting my node module folder and reinstalling webpack along with any other dependencies, and I still come to here. I've also tried other solution I've seen elsewhere to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like that package's `watch` isn't written to work on Windows? `&&` between commands is Bash for OSX and Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Watch is exiting with exit code 1 and npm sprays all that whenever a command returns non-zero exit code. There are some work-arrondissement here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6124